# How to display Python version in 'oh-my-zsh'

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, oh-my-zsh, terminator

I am trying to display the python version next to my python venv using oh-my-zsh with powershell9k theme. Does anyone have any idea how?

I tried adding `virtualenv --version` under `virtualenv` in `~/.p10k.zsh` but it didn't work as I imagined.

Comment: python --version

Comment: Does not work. I set my `.p10k.zsh` file accordingly, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a SemVer version you can use something like this:

```
python --version | sed 's,Python ,,'
```

Comment: I got `/home/daedalous/.p10k.zsh:57: parse error near `|'`

Comment: Put error screenshots, so someone can help you.